# How Microsoft Implemented shell extensions for upcoming OneDrive On-Demand features?

Tags: windows-shell, shell-extensions, shell-namespace-extension

Within the upcoming (currently insider) version of OneDrive client - On-Demand feature Microsoft introduced some new shell / namespace extensions.

There is additional column showing file availability status, and text within the status bar.

Did Microsoft developed special IShellView implementation for OneDrive synced folders, or some other shell interface? How did they hooked up to the file selection change events?

I know that support for Column handler extensions was removed since some previous Windows version.

Please point me to some useful resources regarding the development of such functionalities: custom column and status bar extensions (preferably using C#..).

Comment: Columns can be added via the [Propery System](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728871.aspx), not sure if exposes the status bar

Comment: But the Property System only works on files. the Onedrive column shows a status for folders as well.

Comment: This commercial component: https://www.shellboost.com/Doc/Introduction/Files-On-Demand (disclaimer, I work for the vendor) allows you to write On-Demand folders (using .NET). On-Demand folder is a feature of Windows, supported by the Shell.